# Bash: assigning to a variable using another variable+text

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I'm looking to use a for loop to assign several variables using essentially the same code.

```
#!bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ )); do
    case ${i} in 
        1) filling=apple; a=an ;; 
        2) filling=peach; a=a ;; 
        3) filling=pecan; a=a ;; 
        4) filling=cherry; a=a ;;
    esac
    echo "Would you like ${a} ${filling} pie? Y/N"
    read var1
    case ${var1} in
       Y|y) ${filling}_pie="True" ;; 
       N|n) ${filling}_pie="No" ;;
    esac
done
```

This script works exactly as intended except when it comes to assignign the variables at the end. I get `apple_pie=True: command not found`. I've also tried `Y|y) ${${filling}}_pie="True" ;`, but when I do that I get `bash: ${${filling}}_pie="True": bad substitution`.

Either my shell hates pie, or I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to find an instance of anybody else doing this, or at least I can't an instance of anybody describing it the way I'm trying to describe it when I search on Google...

Is there anyway to get this to assign a variable while using a variable in the assignment?

Comment: You basically want a dynamic name for your variable (get help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`declare` directive](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) here for declaring dynamic variables:

```
declare ${filling}_pie="True"
```