# How to echo a dynamic variable's content in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, variables, unix, scripting

How to echo a dynamic variable's content in shell script ?

```
i=1
declare  x$i=help
echo  $(echo x$i)
echo $x$i
```

*Current output:*

```
x1  
1
```

*Desired output:*

```
help
```

Comment: [bash-dynamic-variable-names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: As you're using `declare`, so you probably are using bash, just use an array.

Comment: I really wish I could use arrays here, but due to some system level conflicts I have to go with this raw way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eval:

```
i=1
declare  x$i=help
eval "echo \$x$i"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo  $(tmpvar=x$i && echo ${!tmpvar})
```

Example:

```
i=1
declare  x$i=help
echo  "$(tmpvar=x$i && echo ${!tmpvar})"
```

Output:

```
help
```