# bash variable array name

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I'm trying to let the user pick the array name because the arrays are sets of domain names.

```
while getopts h:c: option
do
      case "${option}"
      in
      c) client=${OPTARG};
      h) usage;;
esac
done
```

So like I want client=one of the customer arrays

```
customer1=(my_custdomain.com, my_custdomain2.com...)
custmoer2=(my1_custdomain.com, my1c_custdomain2.com...)

for i in client
do
      func_name
done
```

by now I'm really confused about expansions/quotes.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do. You seem to have: a function `func_name` which is passed no arguments; a list of items containing just `client` that you're iterating over with a variable `i` that is never used; it isn't clear what you are storing in `$client` (is it a digit, or the name of the array). I assume that `custmoer2` is a typo; maybe you meant to use `for i in $client`. Maybe you're simply looking for the `${!var}` notation for indirect expansion. Maybe you need to read the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need indirect parameter expansion.

```
# No commas
customer1=(my_custdomain.com my_custdomain2.com)
customer2=(my1_custdomain.com my1c_custdomain2.com)

arrayref=$client[@]
for i in "${!arrayref}"; do
do
      func_name
done
```

Comment: Perfect, Worked great.  Thank U. Thank U. Thank U.