# Assigning a shell variable name where the variable name comes from a for loop

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I am able run a script that contains

```
for fname in deletions
do
        numdeletions=$(ls -l ${2}/deletions{[1-9],[1-9][0-9]}.txt | wc -l)
done
```

And it works just fine

However when script contains

```
for fname in deletions
do
        num${fname}=$(ls -l ${2}/deletions{[1-9],[1-9][0-9]}.txt | wc -l)
done
```

I get

```
./testScript.sh: line 4: numdeletions=: command not found
```

How am I able to fix this

Comment: It is *very* bad practice to use dynamic variable names in almost all programming languages. Are you sure you need this? (The answer is usually "no".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash dynamic variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: Please take a look at the linked duplicate, you'll see what you *should* do instead of this:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah I'm sure I wanna do this

Comment: Application like this are what bash's _associative arrays_ were made for. Is there a reason why you don't want to use them here?