# How to store comma separated value in different set of variable using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I've below string in my shell script:

```
myString="app.mykey.value1,app.mykey.value2,app.mykey.value3,app.mykey.value4"
```

After splitting the comma separated value, I want to store each value in a different variable. For example:

```
var1=app.mykey.value1
var2=app.mykey.value2
var3=app.mykey.value3
var4=app.mykey.value4
```

How can i achieve this in shell script?

Comment: well, short answer is, no, you can't. because you cannot generate variable names in runtime without resorting to `eval`, which you don't want to use. however, you can indeed make it to an array. is that ok to you?

Comment: `IFS=, read -r -a myArray <<<"$myString"` will make `${myArray[0]}` be `app.mykey.value1`, `${myArray[1]}` be `app.mykey.value2`, etc -- which is the Right Thing here.

Comment: ...that said, there *are* ways to do indirect assignment less evil than `eval`, and we *do* have Q&A entries describing them here on the site. See [Dynamic variable names in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

To generate `var1`, `var2`, etc safely, use `declare`:

```
readarray -td, vals <<<"$myString"
i=1
for val in "${vals[@]}"
do
    declare "var$((i++))=$val"
done
```

For most purposes, though, you are better off using the array `vals` directly rather than creating the shell variables `var1`, ....

Comment: You mean `"${vals[@]}"`, no?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for catching that typo!