# Set value of dynamic var in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following case:

```
A=1
echo $A # output 1
B='A'
echo $B  # output A
echo "\$$B=2" # output $A=2
echo "\$$B=2" | eval # this won't set $A to 2
```

I'd like `$A` to get `2` as value.

Comment: Please be clear about "this won't work means"

Comment: Why are you piping into `eval`. Did you mean `eval "\$$B=2"`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist fixed my question. `eval "\$$B=2"` won't set $A

Comment: @codeforester thanks it was what i was looking for, just with no arrays

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using `declare` ( [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash) )

```
B='A'
declare "$B=2"
echo $A # output 2
```