# Echo a variable with an index at the end in bash script

Tags: bash, echo

I am trying to allocate a bunch of temp files in a loop and export them from within the loop. I then want to loop thru again and echo the values.

```
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ ))
do
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/mh1_$i.out bs=1024 count=1024 status=none
    declare TEMP_FILE_${i}="/tmp/mh1_${i}.out"
    export "TEMP_FILE_${i}"  
done
```

If I do a `echo $TEMP_FILE_1` it correctly prints `/tmp/mh1_1.out`

But when I try this in a loop it prints `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`.

```
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ ))
do
    echo $TEMP_FILE_${i} --> This prints the i value instead of /tmp/mh1_x.out
done
```

How do I escape the index `$i` in the `echo` above to see the real file name ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124325/3776858

Comment: Why do you want to `export` them?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the [`mktemp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mktemp-invocation.html) utility with arrays:

```
# create tmp files
tmp_files=()
for ((i=0;i<5;++i)); do
    tmp_files+=("$(mktemp --tmpdir mh1_XXXXXX.out)") || exit 1
done

# process all tmp files
for file in "${tmp_files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
    # do something with the file ...
done

# list all tmp files
printf '%s\n' "${tmp_files[@]}"

# list 2nd tmp file
echo "${tmp_files[1]}"
```

---

In order to make **your** code work, you need to use [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and change your second `for` loop to:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;++i)); do
    var=temp_file_$i
    echo "${!var}"
done
```

Don't use uppercase variables as they could clash with environmental or internal shell variables. Also, note that [`export`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) is needed only when you want to pass the variables to child processes in the environment.

Comment: No need for a loop to print the elements of an array: `printf '%s\n' "${tmp_files[@]}"`

Comment: @Kusalananda It felt like a reasonable assumption that OP might want to process the files in some way, hence the loop. Good point though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use bash arrays?

```
export temp_file
loop
    temp_file[$i]="/tmp/mh1_${i}.out"
    ...
endloop
```

Then loop over the array

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot `export` an array. But I don't think OP wants to `export` it anyway.

Comment: I would down check my answer if I could.  It is "correct" in that it suggests arrays but "meh" in that I was too tired to think clearly when I wrote it.