# Can i use cut to set a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, cut

I want to cut a variable and use the result to manipulate a variable at this name

```
`echo ${!var1} | cut -b$var2`=1
```

But thats don't work. Do you have any idea to do that ?

The complete code

```
for (( var1=1; ${!var1}!=""; var1++ )) 
    do for (( var2=1; `echo ${!var1} | cut -b$var2`!=""; var2++ ))
        do `echo ${!var1} | cut -b$var2`=1 
    done
done
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/560648

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables

Comment: A concrete example would help, but anything involving setting a variable whose name is calculated at run time will need to involve `printf -v`.

Comment: I have `var0 = abcdef` and i want to assign `f = 1`. For that i want to extract the "f" of var0. Here `var2 = 6`. `var1 = var0`, so he will invoke var0

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
ref=${!var1}
printf -v "${ref:$var2:1}" '%s' 1
```

Comment: With quotes! and I think the PE `${!var1:var2:1}` works (can't test now).

Comment: And maybe `declare` or `printf -v` instead of `eval` would be slightly less dangerous...