# How to get word x from a string

Tags: bash, sh

I want to read a file line by line as following:

```
while read line;
do
  set -- $line
  c=$#  #count words and save as $c
  r=$(( RANDOM%c ))
  #here i'd like to get the word on position r from $line
done < words.txt
```

I know, I can get word 1 as following:

```
set -- $line
echo $1
```

But how can I replace 1 with the integer saved in $r?

Comment: Related: [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection):

```
echo "${!r}"
```

For example:

```
$ set -- a b c
$ echo $2
b
$ v=2
$ echo ${!v}
b
```

Comment: On second thought, don't do this. Use an array instead. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793714/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

Use an [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) instead:

```
words=($line)
echo "${words[$r]}"
```

For example:

```
$ var words
declare -a words='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")'
$ v=2
$ echo "${words[v]}"
c
$ echo "${words[v-1]}"
b
```