# Bash pass a string in a function and echo that string as the global variable

Tags: bash

How can I echo the `value` of $globevar?

```
globevar="testing something"

somefunc() {
 echo $1 #will echo exactly whats passed
 echo ${$1} # errors out
}
```

somefunc globevar # globevar

somefunc globevar # -bash: ${$1}: bad substitution

Comment: Are you looking for indirect expansion, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash/18124325#18124325)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)