# selecting blocks of strings

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#
dm1="test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com"
dm2="test4@gmail.com, test5@gmail.com, test6@gmail.com"
dm3="test7@gmail.com, test8@gmail.com, test9@gmail.com"
#
read -p "type: dm1, dm2 or dm3 to select: " blocks
```

I need that variable $blocks will contains not the string dm1, dm2 or dm3 but the contents of dm1, dm2 or dm3 variables to redirect to mutt to send email

Comment: Have a look at [dynamic variables in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Comment: Look into `select` as well, instead of building your own menu functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
dm1="test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com"
blocks="dm1"
echo "${!blocks}"
```

Output:

```
test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a single array, whether indexed

```
dms=("test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com"
     "test4@gmail.com, test5@gmail.com, test6@gmail.com"
     "test7@gmail.com, test8@gmail.com, test9@gmail.com")
```

or associative

```
declare -A dms
dms=([dm1]="test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com"
     [dm2]="test4@gmail.com, test5@gmail.com, test6@gmail.com"
     [dm3]="test7@gmail.com, test8@gmail.com, test9@gmail.com")
```

Then the user can an appropriate key (or you can map the input to the appropriate key in a `case` statement), and you can expand `"${dms[$key]}"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `select` is as simple as:

```sh
PS3="Which block? "
select blocks in "$dm1" "$dm2" "$dm3"; do
  [[ $blocks ]] && break
done
echo "You selected: $blocks"
```