# Can you use a varialben to build a variable in Gitlab CI?

Tags: variables, gitlab, cicd

Is it possible in a gitlab CICD pipline to build a variable dynamically with a variable?
Sample:
i have a variable in gitlab "TEST_MASTER".

```
script:
- echo "$TEST_"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH""
```

I need the result from the variable TEST_MASTER, but the part of MASTER must come from the branch variable.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bash script to me so assuming `TEST_MASTER` already has a value, you should be able echo it like this:

```
script:
- myvar=TEST_"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
  echo "${!myvar}"
```

For more information, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash) question and it's answers

Comment: well, it not only partly bash!
it comes from the gitlab-ci.yml. Yes, you can run bash here but the variables are not available at bash level, the values from the variables are sort of inserted on execution.

Comment: master
`$ myvar=TEST_"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"`
`$ echo "${!myvar}"`
`/bin/sh: eval: line 136: syntax error: bad substitution`
`Cleaning up file based variables`
Unfortunately does not work!