# Cannot install bash in nginx:alpine

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# => Build container
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app

# split the dependecies from our source code so docker builds can cache this step
# (unless we actually change dependencies)
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build

# => Run container
FROM nginx:alpine

# Nginx config
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Default port exposure
EXPOSE 8080

# Copy .env file and shell script to container
COPY --from=builder /app/dist .
COPY ./env.sh .
COPY .env .

USER root

# Add bash
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash

# Make our shell script executable
RUN chmod +x env.sh

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

But when I try to run it I get the following errors when trying to add `bash`:

```
------
 > [stage-1 8/9] RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash:
#19 0.294 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#19 0.358 140186175183688:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
#19 0.360 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#19 0.360 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: Permission denied
#19 0.360 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory
#19 0.405 140186175183688:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
#19 0.407 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: Permission denied
#19 0.407 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory
#19 0.408 2 errors; 42 distinct packages available
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add --no-cache bash]: exit code: 2
```

Which I need to add to execute this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Recreate config file
rm -rf ./env-config.js
touch ./env-config.js

# Add assignment 
echo "window._env_ = {" >> ./env-config.js

# Read each line in .env file
# Each line represents key=value pairs
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
  # Split env variables by character `=`
  if printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -q -e '='; then
    varname=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/=.*//')
    varvalue=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//')
  fi

  # Read value of current variable if exists as Environment variable
  value=$(printf '%s\n' "${!varname}")
  # Otherwise use value from .env file
  [[ -z $value ]] && value=${varvalue}
  
  # Append configuration property to JS file
  echo "  $varname: \"$value\"," >> ./env-config.js
done < .env

echo "}" >> ./env-config.js
```

From what I have read adding `USER root` should fix this but it does not in this case.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: It looks like an SSL validation failure ("tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"). When was the last time you ran `docker pull node:14-alpine`? I wonder if you're affected by the [LetsEncrypt certificate expiration](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/), and you just need to update your image.

Comment: Although the answer and comment are to-the-point, are you aware that an Alpine box already ships with `ash`? Based on your actual use case, `ash` could be fine enough already.

Comment: I get the same bad substitution error using ash unfrotunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `/bin/sh` as a standard Bourne shell; also, you should be able to avoid the `sh -c` wrapper in the `CMD` line.

First, rewrite the script using [POSIX shell syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html).  Scanning over the script, it seems like it is almost okay as-is; change the first line to `#!/bin/sh`, and correct the non-standard `${!varname}` expansion (also see [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash))

```sh
# Read value of current variable if exists as Environment variable
value=$(sh -c "echo \$$varname")
# Otherwise use value from .env file
[[ -z $value ]] && value=${varvalue}
```

You can try testing it using an `alpine` or `busybox` image with a more restricted shell, or setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable with bash.

Secondly, there's a reasonably standard pattern of [using `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  The `CMD` gets passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`, so if the `ENTRYPOINT` ends with `exec "$@"`, it will replace itself with that command.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^ not bash

# Recreate config file
...
echo "window._env_ = {" >> ./env-config.js
...
echo "}" >> ./env-config.js

# Run the main container CMD
exec "$@"
```

Now, in your Dockerfile, you don't need to install GNU bash, because you're not using it, but you do need to correctly split out the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]          # can be either syntax
```

As an aside, the `cmd1 && cmd2` syntax is basic shell syntax and not a bash extension, so you could write `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cmd1 && cmd2"]`; but, if you write a command without the JSON array syntax, Docker will insert the `sh -c` wrapper for you.  You should almost never need to write out `sh -c` in a Dockerfile.

Comment: When i convert it to shell syntax i get the following error when running the container /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh: line 28: syntax error: bad substitution and do not see the variables being replaced by the environment variables passed with the docker run command

Comment: docker run --env AUTH0_DOMAIN=integration.eu.auth0.com --env AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=ourclientid --env AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:1337 --env AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE=https://tdev.co.uk -it --rm -p 1337:8080 sample:dev

Comment: I see, `${!varname}` is not standard; I've edited a workaround into the question.

Comment: You also might consider using a higher-level language for this setup, if your environment otherwise has Node or Python available for example.