# Dynamic Variable assignmenet in ShellScript - How to?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two variables in my bash script

```
CAR_PRICE=50000
BIKE_PRICE=20000
```

I am passing a command line argument while executing my .sh shell script file.

```
--vehicletype CAR  or --vehicletype BIKE
```

I am able to read the vehicletype value in the script  and store in another varible

```
VEHICLE_TYPE=<VALUE PASSED FROM COMMAND LINE ARG i.e CAR/BIKE
```

Now I am trying to dynamically read  CAR_PRICE or BIKE_PRICE using following syntax

```
${${VEHICLE_TYPE}_PRICE}
```

to get the values of the params subtituting the first part of the variable
dynamically based on the value passwed ie but it is throwing **Bad Substitution error**.

I tried several ways but nothing seem to work. I am new to shell script and not sure if such
dynamic substitution is supported in bash script.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: It would be safer to use a `case "${VEHICLE_TYPE}" in ...` to find the corresponding price

Comment: I want to make things generic with no hardcoding of custom values in script hence passing from outside so that the --vehicletype would be optional param , introducing case would make script tightly coupled CAR_PRICE=50000
BIKE_PRICE=20000 are being read from property file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indirect variable reference in `bash`:

```sh
CAR_PRICE=50000
BIKE_PRICE=20000
VEHICLE_TYPE='CAR'
var="${VEHICLE_TYPE}_PRICE"

# variable name
echo "$var"
# variable value
echo "${!var}"
```

**Output:**

```sh
CAR_PRICE
50000
```

Comment: @anubhava As a veteran here, I am surprised you forgot to mention this earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124325/7939871

Answer (score 4):

You can use `price=${VEHICLE_TYPE}_PRICE; echo "${!price}"`. However, associative arrays are a better tool for this job:

```
declare -A vehicle_price
vehicle_price[ford]=7777
vehicle_price[toyota]=8888

vehicle_type=toyota
echo "${vehicle_price[$vehicle_type]}"
# gives
8888
```

Comment: That probably won't be a problem but it needs bash >= 4

Comment: @Fravadona 100% true. However since bash 4.0 was released twelve years ago (2009), I think we're at a point where it's only worth mentioning if the OS is Mac, or the questioner says they're on an older platform.

Comment: @dan this is a good answer but a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553351/7939871