# How to echo a variable (name of which contains another varibale)

Tags: shell, echo, csh

I was writing a small shell script to read and print lines of
a file.

```
#!/bin/csh

set IN_FILE=$1
set i=1
foreach line ( "`cat $IN_FILE`" )
  set F$i="`echo $line`"
  echo ${F${i}}
  @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Upon executing, I am getting the following error

```
Missing '}'.
```

I was wondering how to echo a variable, which contains
another variable in its name.

Comment: Tried to use eval? In bash, try "help eval".

Comment: eval ${F${i}} gives the same error.

Comment: Mind always quoting. What parameter do you pass to your script?

Comment: You can use `echo ${!i}`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124325/724039  (or is this bash only ?)

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I am passing the name of a file, which it has to read and print each lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have csh, so tried this with bash. The content of test.sh is:

```
i=1
eval "F$i=\"this is a line\""
eval echo "test: " \${F$i}
echo "F1 is" $F1
```

and it seems to work:

```
 /tmp$ ./test.sh
 test: this is a line
 F1 is this is a line
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

```
#!/bin/csh

set IN_FILE=$1
set i=1
foreach line ( "`cat $IN_FILE`" )
  eval "set F$i='`echo $line`'"
  eval echo \${F$i}
  @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Thanks a lot linuxfan for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Found an example here: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/275206-issue-nesting-variables-csh.html    and tried to adapt it to your script

Try:

```
#!/bin/csh

set IN_FILE=$1
set i=1
set j=1
foreach line ( "`cat $IN_FILE`" )
  #set F$i="`echo $line`"
  #echo ${F${i}}
  set test=( F${i} )
  echo "$test[$j]"
  @ i = $i + 1
end
```

found an example here: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/275206-issue-nesting-variables-csh.html

and tried to adapt it to your script