# How to create a variable from an argument in bash

Tags: bash

I have a small problem:
I enter the command tag -f F1    into my terminal which means using my tag programme find the tag f1 in the current directory. I've stored a list of all the tags and their paths in a separate file called tagslist which I read in order to print the path to the user like in the picture. However, the problem is I need to turn the F1 argument into $F1 so I can search for it in my file.

```
source $(dirname "$0")/tagslist
echo "the location of $tag1 is: $(dirname "$0")/$F1"
```

I can't just do:

```
tag=$2
source $(dirname "$0")/tagslist
echo "the location of $tag1 is: $(dirname "$0")/$tag"
```

as $tag does not exist in the tagslist file, only F1

If anyone would be willing to share some wizardry to fix this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Please show a *concrete* example of your command. Show us a sample output of `ls -la` for the target directory of your command and the desired result of your command.

Comment: "... like in the picture." - *Which* picture?

Comment: What is `$tag1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the `$tag` variable name indirectly, you use `${!tag}`.

See this very active topic already discussing: [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash).

Here is a working version of your code sample:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tag=$2

# shellcheck disable=SC1090 # dynamic source
source "${0%/*}/tagslist"

printf 'The location of %s is: %s\n' "$tag" "${0%/*}/${!tag}"
```

Comment: `"${0%/*}"` differs from `"$(dirname "$0")"` when `$0` doesn't contain a `/` character.