# How to make a string, not a value of a variable but a new variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have these variables:

```
var1=ab
var2=cd
result=${var1}-text-${var2}
ab-text-cd=bingo
```

I have:

```
$ echo $result
ab-text-cd
```

I would like to have:

```
$ echo $result
bingo
```

Is it possible and how?

More info:
Var1 and var2 are arguments given to script.

Comment: Does this answers your question [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indirect parameter expansion is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Léa Gris.
I didn't know about "indirect parameter expansion".

```
"If the first character of PARAMETER is an exclamation point, Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of PARAMETER as the name of the variable."
```

Solution :

```
result2=$(echo ${!result1})
```

Comment: The `echo` is wholly unnecessary. `result2=${!result1}` does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` to achieve this. Be warned though, that using `eval` is almost always a bad idea, as it has glaring security issues (rooted in its design -- it is meant to execute everything passed to it) and even apart from that, all kinds of things might go wrong when a variable has an unexpected value.

```
result=${var1}-text-${var2}
eval ${var1}'_text_'${var2}=bingo
echo $ab_text_cd
```

Also, environment variables cannot have dashes (-) as part of the variable name, so I replaced them by underscores (_) for the example.

Comment: Hi ! Yeah I use underscores but when I was writing my question they wouldn't appear so I replaced them with dashes.
Tried eval already but it wasn't what I was looking for.
The "bingo" string is something I can "call" but not a string I chose because it depends on $var1 and $var2. They can have 5 different values each.

Comment: Since the question is tagged `bash`, there's really no need to even mention `eval`.

Comment: Also, there are no environment variables in this scenario. (You *can*, in fact, store names containing `-` in the environment of a process; those names just aren't exposed as ordinary *shell* variables.)