# how to create a variable for evaluation in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a CSV that says this:

```
Source,Target,Database,Table,Is_deletable,Action
DBServer1,DBServer2,DB,TBL1,true,Add
DBServer2,DBServer1,DB,TBL2,true,Add
```

I have shell script that does this:

```
while IFS=, read -r source target database table is_deletable action; do
    echo "Building pipeline for ${database}.${table}";
              total=$((total+1))
              Shost="server1.myorganization.com"
              Thost="server2.myorganization.com"
```

I need Shost to look like this:

```
Shost = ${'the value of the source column'}
Thost = ${'the value of the target column'}
```

How do I set this to evaluate dynamically the variable I need based on the value of the column data.

For example:

```
Shost=${DBServer1}
Thost=${DBServer2}
```

then on the next loop:

```
Shost=${DBServer2}
Thost=${DBServer1}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you going to do with `$Shost` and `$Thost` variables?

Comment: they will be referenced later on in a CURL call.  this is a build script.

Comment: the variables are made available in the environmental section of a build engine. in this case Octopus.  So in Octopus, I have all of my servers saved, so I can have this script just refer to them dynamically.  this let's me keep the code static in different environments (Dev, QA, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```sh
DBServer1='server1.myorganization.com'
DBServer2='server2.myorganization.com'

while IFS=, read -r source target database table is_deletable action; do
   [[ $source = "Source" ]] && continue
   ((total++))
   Shost="${!source}"
   Thost="${!target}"

   # check variables Shost Thost total
   declare -p Shost Thost total
done < file.csv

declare -- Shost="server1.myorganization.com"
declare -- Thost="server2.myorganization.com"
declare -- total="1"
declare -- Shost="server2.myorganization.com"
declare -- Thost="server1.myorganization.com"
declare -- total="2"
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I think you would need to use `eval` somewhere to evaluate `$Shost` recursively.

Comment: I think I misunderstood question initially assuming OP wants literally `${DBServer1}`. Corrected it now. Thanks!

Comment: thank you anubhava.  what is this line: `[[ $source = "Source" ]] && continue` for?

Comment: `[ $source = "Source" ]] && continue` is for skipping first header line in your csv file

Comment: @WilliamPursell My comment preceded (and prompted) the edit that added `${!...}`

Comment: Note that, unless you control the name carefully, indirect variable expansion can cause arbitrary code execution.  It's as dangerous as `eval`.  See this [comment by St&#233;phane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281390/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-indirect-array-in-bash#comment665388_281390), and the "Risks" section of the [answer by Ma&#235;lan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55331060/4154375) to [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/4154375).

Comment: Even if you check that the `source` and `target` values are identifiers there's a danger that they will reference unexpected variables, potentially causing unwanted information leaks.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash -- but not necessarily in other shells -- you can reference a variable indirectly, exactly as you seem to want to do:

```
$ DBServer1=db1.my.com
$ source=DBServer1
$ echo ${source}
DBServer1
$ echo ${!source}
db1.my.com
```

As the Bash manual puts it ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

> If [in a parameter expansion of the
> form `${parameter}`] the first character of `parameter`  is an exclamation point (!), and `parameter` is
> not a `nameref`, it  introduces a level of variable indirection.  Bash
> uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of `parameter` as
> the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that
> value is used in the rest  of  the substitution,  rather than the
> value of parameter itself.

Applying that to your sample code and data, we get

```
DBServer1=server1.myorganization.com
DBServer2=server2.myorganization.com

# ...

while IFS=, read -r source target database table is_deletable action; do
    echo "Building pipeline for ${database}.${table}";
              total=$((total+1))
              Shost="${!source}"
              Thost="${!target}"
```

Comment: Note that, unless you control the name carefully, indirect variable expansion can cause arbitrary code execution.  It's as dangerous as `eval`.  See this [comment by St&#233;phane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281390/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-indirect-array-in-bash#comment665388_281390), and the "Risks" section of the [answer by Ma&#235;lan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55331060/4154375) to [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/4154375).

Comment: Even if you check that the `source` and `target` values are valid identifiers there's a danger that they will reference unexpected variables, potentially causing unwanted information leaks.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use an associative array for this problem:

```sh
declare -A servers=(
    [DBServer1]='server1.myorganization.com'
    [DBServer2]='server2.myorganization.com'
)

{
    read header
    while IFS=, read -r source target database table is_deletable action; do
        Shost=${servers[$source]}
        Thost=${servers[$target]}
        ...
    done
} < file.csv
```