# Dynamic variable in SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have 3 different array as follows(ignore the actual values)

```
first_array=(123 456 657)
second_array=(11 22 33)
third_array=(29 45 56)
```

so i have a case where i need to pass these arrays one by one as an argument to a shell file

```
sh test.sh "${first_array[@]}"
```

but what im working on is a for loop as follows

```
arrays=("first" "second" "third")
for n in ${arrays[@]}; do
   array=${n}_array
   nohup sh test.sh "${!array[@]}" > log_${n} &   <-some error here, array not going in
done
```

Please help me on how to write for loop for such case

Comment: I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash) with multiples replies. See if one of then help's you

Comment: If you have a recent enough version of bash you can use namerefs: `declare -n tmp="${n}_array"; nohup sh test.sh "${tmp[@]}"...`.

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent enough version of `bash` you can use `namerefs`:

```sh
for n in ${arrays[@]}; do
  declare -n tmp="${n}_array"
  nohup sh test.sh "${tmp[@]}" > "log_${n}" &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
arrays=(first second third)
for n in "${arrays[@]}"; do
    array_ref="${n}_array[@]"
    nohup sh test.sh "${!array_ref}" > "log_$n" &
done
```