# bash setting variable getting error command not found

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm writing one small bash script for my Project
but i getting some errors

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(cat Downloads/datei.csv | wc -l);
for((i=115;i<="122";i++)); do
line$i=$(sed -n $i"p" Downloads/datei.csv);
echo "line$i";
done
```

i trying to get every line from CSV in some variable

The erroŕ

> count.sh: line 4: line115=: command not found

```
if [[ -z "line$i" ]];
then
      echo "$i is empty";
else
      echo "$i is NOT empty";
fi
```

the second code gives me the same error

Comment: this two code block could not compose together?

Comment: they can be composed together but i get the error command not found.

Comment: The problem you ran into is the topic of [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: Oneliner: `mapfile -s 114 -n 8 -t linearray < Downloads/datei.csv` this puts the lines 115 to 122 in an ARRAY and you can access e.g. line 119 it by: `echo ${linearray[119]}`

Answer (score 0):

Suggest compose the code together, just update `line$i` to a temporary normal variable without other var like `line_get`.

One more thing, you need to update `-z "line$i"` to `-z "$line_get"`. As in `bash`, you should use `$` and the var name to get the value.
Looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(cat Downloads/datei.csv | wc -l)
for((i=115;i<=122;i++)); do
    line_get=$(sed -n $i"p" Downloads/datei.csv)
    if [[ -z "$line_get" ]];
    then
        echo "$i is empty"
    else
        echo "$i is NOT empty"
    fi
done
```

If you need to [dynamic generate the variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash). Try this:

```
declare "line$i=$(sed -n $i"p" Downloads/datei.csv)" 
var="line$i"
echo "${!var}"
```

And `echo "line$i";` just print the text like `line115` but not the value of the variable `line$1`.

Comment: I need this var for the rest of my script