# Creating variables in running script

Tags: bash

I'm trying convert some files to read only in backup environment. Data Domain has retention-lock feature that can lock files with external trigger which `touch -a -t "dateuntillocked" /backup/foo`.
In this situation there is also metadata files in folder that should not be locked otherwise next backup job cannot update metadata file and fails.
I extracted metadata file names but file count can be changed. For exp.
`foo1.meta foo2.meta . . fooN.meta`

Is it possible to create a variable for each entry and add to command dynamically?
Like:
var1=/backup/foo234.meta
var2=/backup/foo322.meta
.
.
varN=/backup/fooNNN.meta

```
<find command> | grep -v $var1 $var2....varN | while read line; do touch -a -t "$dateuntillocked" "$line"; done
```

another elaboration of the case is
for example you executed a ls in a folder but amount of file can differs in time. script will create a variable for every file and use in a touch command with while loop. if 3 files in folder, script will create 3 variable and use 3 variable with touch in while loop. if "ls" result find 4 files, script dynamically create 4 variable fof files and use all in while loop etc. I am not a programmer so my logic can differ. May be another way to do this with easier way.

Comment: It's not clear what your sample code has to do with your question.

Comment: That said, it looks like you want to use an array, to dynamically expand a command line, as described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Also, to let changes it makes to your array persist, you'll need to change the way you get data into your `while read` loop for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: ...for more on bash arrays, see [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Comment: ...but to provide an actual _answer_, as opposed to a bunch of relevant-looking links, I'll need a [mre] -- code I can run myself without changes to see the same problem, with stated desired output that if present would imply that it's fixed / operating as-intended.

Comment: refer to this , might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing what your intentions might be.

You can combine `find | grep | command` into a single command:

```
find /backup -name 'foo*.meta' -exec touch -a -t "$dateuntillocked" {} +
```

Comment: If you have to guess, isn't that an indication that a close-as-unclear vote is called for?