# Gitlab CI: can I use variable in another variable name?

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline, variable-assignment

I know I can use variables in variables, for example:

```
script:
  - SOME_VAR=text_${VAR1}
```

but how can I use variable IN the name of a new variable?

```
script:
  - VAR1=TEXT1
  - SOME_NEW_VAR_${VAR1}=some_text
```

It doesn't work this way:

```
SOME_NEW_VAR_TEXT1=some_text: command not found
```

Looks like Gitlab create text correctly, but can't get I want to create it as new variable.

**Is it possible in some way?**
I use template to create specific variables in different jobs and want to recognise which variable from which job.

---

Full example:

```
.template: &template
  image: $common/specificImage:latest
  stage: build
  script: 
    - echo "Startin process..."
    - SOME_VAR_${PROJECT_NAME}=$( ls )

first-job:
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: ProjectA
  <<: *template

second-job:
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: ProjectB
  <<: *template
```

ERROR:

```
/scripts-123-456/step_script: line 192: SOME_VAR_ProjectA=sometext: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indirect/reference variables, for example1:

```
first-job:
  image: ubuntu:22.04
  script:
    - VAR1="TEXT1"
    - declare SOME_NEW_VAR_${VAR1}="some_text"
    - varname=SOME_NEW_VAR_${VAR1}
    - echo $varname
    - echo "${!varname}"
```

output:

```
$ echo $varname
SOME_NEW_VAR_TEXT1
$ echo "${!varname}"
some_text
```

---

example 2:

```
.template: &template
  image: ubuntu:22.04
  script:
    - VAR1=$PROJECT_NAME
    - VAR2=`ls`
    - declare "SOME_NEW_VAR_${VAR1}=$VAR2"
    - varname=SOME_NEW_VAR_${VAR1}
    - echo $varname
    - echo "${!varname}"

first-job:
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: ProjectA
  <<: *template

second-job:
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: ProjectB
  <<: *template
```

reference:

- [BashFAQ/006 - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection)
- [Dynamic variable names in Bash - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Comment: Hi, thank you for response! While I'm trying to figure it out, maybe you can check my another question about gitlab?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I am updating my example; add example 2 for your GitLab question.