# How to get variables config from shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

cat a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
t=1232
echo $1
#echo $t
```

when i run the script "./a.sh $t"  I can't get value 1232
when the script replacement with echo $t ,run the script "./a.sh" can get vaule 1232

can anybody else tell me ,if i use "./a.sh $t" this form ,how can get the vaule,thanks alot

have no ideas to get the variables throug the termi

Comment: The script consists only of this single line???? Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Does ["How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) answer your question? If not, please clarify what your goal is.

Comment: `$t` gets evaluated immediately, the script you are running simply receives whatever it evaluated to in `$1` (probably nothing). I'm guessing maybe you are looking for [indirect references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `"./a.sh $t` your current shell evaluates `$t` to '' so `$1` is unset in your script and it will just execute `echo`.

If you quote the the variable either `./a.sh \$t` or `./a.sh '$t'` your script will do `echo '$t'`.  You can then use either eval to get it to evaluate the expression:

```
eval echo "$1"
```

or preferable strip off the leading '$' and use indirect variable:

```
var=${1:1}
echo "${!var}"
```

If you just need to store data use json or sqlite instead of a script.

If you have logic in your script consider just passing in the variable names and if not set dump all variables (using the name convention that your variables are lower case):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    set | grep "^[a-z]"
    exit 0
fi
for v in "$@"
do
    set | grep "^$v="
done
```

and you then do:

```
$ ./a t
t=1232
$ ./a
t=1232
```

Comment: Actually, without quotes, it simply leaves `$1` unset if the variable `t` was empty or unset in the calling shell. Perhaps also see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee I don't think that I am anything different.  `$1` is unset because `$t` is being evaluated by calling shell.  Clarified it, hope it addresses your concern.

Comment: I'm afraid it's actually still incorrect; you are running `echo`, not `echo ''`. Probably add quoting to your solution, though with `eval`, I can't really say what the correct quoting would look like.

Comment: @tripleee Neither seems wrong to me but not really sure.  The code is `echo $1` and if a variable is not set it evaluates to '', right?  $(echo) = $(echo '').  Do you have a reference for why `echo ''` is "wrong"?  I revised answer assuming that I am wrong, btw, but still curios.

Comment: `echo` is a bad example as such because it prints an empty line in both cases. There are many other commands where an empty argument does something different than no argument; try e.g. `cat ''` vs `cat`, for example. So it does matter to keep them separate and distinct, especially when trying to explain what actually is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable `t` are out of scope. Therefore, what you want to do is assign the variable `t=1232`, beforehand, and use it as an argument. So the script would be

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

Then call the script as you wanted to with variable `t` already assigned to the value, so it would print the desired output

```
t=1232
./script.sh $t
```

I think that's that. would love to hear your thoughts tho