# Append a variable to an environment variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have an environment variable as

```
slack_auth_token_test="x0xb-xxxxx-xxxx"
```

my script

*./script.sh test*

```
slack_channel=${1}
echo "token for slack channel is"
echo "${slack_auth_token_[$slack_channel]}"
```

and I am passing the channel `test` as a parameter. So I am looking for a way to append this  channel name `test` to the environment variable and get the token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Comment: Make the name in a variable like: `varname=slack_auth_token_"$slack_channel"` and then you can reference the environment variable with `"${!varname}"`

Comment: thank you @tjm3772 for the quick response. I forgot to put the `!` while calling the referenced variable

Answer (score 3):

With bash, you can use a nameref:

```bash
$ slack_auth_token_test="x0xb-xxxxx-xxxx"
$ set -- test
$ declare -n token="slack_auth_token_$1"
$ echo "$token"
x0xb-xxxxx-xxxx
```