# Bash: Dynamically create variables with the variable name based on a filename

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, dynamic

This question comes from a desire to reduce some repetition in a bash script, around checking if we have something in a file and if so, loading the first line of it into a variable of the same name.

At the moment, there are **dozens** of lines like this for each variable used throughout:

```
[[ -s './config/foo' ]] && read -r foo < './config/foo' || echo "problem with ./config/foo file"
[[ -s './config/bar' ]] && read -r foo < './config/bar' || echo "problem with ./config/foo file"
```

But rather than going through way too many lines like this, I thought I could maybe automate this process by using an array (and also later, expand to other tests with this method).

So I started on the code below, but got stuck at wondering if it's possible to create variable names dynamically? I have no idea how to do that, or if it's even possible. I know I can get the name of the file we would want to use for making the variable name by using `${file##*/}` to strip off the paths (so `./config/foo` becomes `foo` for example), but how to turn that result into a variable name and then set it to the contents of the first line of a file, like the original script does?

Here's what I have so far, where `DYNAMIC_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE` would be the name we can get from `${file##*/}`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check and load config files
required_files=(
  './config/foo'
  './config/bar'
)
for file in "${required_files[@]}"; do
  [[ -s "${file}" ]] && read -r DYNAMIC_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE < "${file}" || failed+=("${file}")
done
if [[ ${#failed[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "there is a problem with the following configuration files:"
  for file in "${failed[@]}"; do
    echo "${file}"
  done
fi

# check
echo "foo: ${foo}"
echo "bar: ${bar}"
```

#### Output so far

```
foo:
bar:
```

#### Desired output

```
foo: [first line of ./config/foo file]
bar: [first line of ./config/bar file]
```

Comment: It's possible, but why do it if you can use an associative array?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, you might have to help me understand what you mean... Sorry! Is there a different approach that could achieve the same result? I'm of course open to that :)

Comment: You said it in the question: "I thought I could maybe automate this process by using an array". So just use an array rather than dynamic variables. `array[$file]`

Comment: Maybe `mytFileToProcess=${file##*/}` would help you (right at the top of your `for` loop, then reference that instead of `$file`.  OR I don't understand  your requirement. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Comment: See [BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ head foo bar
==> foo <==
1st line from foo
2nd line from foo

==> bar <==
1st line from bar
2nd line from bar
```

---

If using `bash 4.2+` you could use a nameref, eg:

```
for fname in foo bar
do
    declare -n curr_var="${fname}"             # nameref
    read -r curr_var < "${fname}"
done
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p foo bar
declare -- foo="1st line from foo"
declare -- bar="1st line from bar"
```

One problem with this approach is ... how do you keep track of the dynamically generated variable names.  In this case we've hardcoded the variable names `foo` and `bar` in the code, but what if there were 10 files, and we don't know (programmatically) beforehand what the file/variable names are ... how/where do you keep track of the variable names?

---

A different approach using an associative array:

```
unset      myvar                               # insure array name not in use
declare -A myvar                               # define Associative array

for fname in *                                 # for now assume this matches on files "foo" and "bar"
do
    read -r myvar[$fname] < "${fname}"
done
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p myvar
declare -A myvar=([bar]="1st line from bar" [foo]="1st line from foo" )
```

Furthermore, we can get a list of our variable names by perusing the indices of the array, eg:

```
for varname in "${!myvar[@]}"                  # loop through array indices
do
    echo "varname = ${varname} : contents: ${myvar[$varname]}"
done
```

This generates:

```
varname = bar : contents: 1st line from bar
varname = foo : contents: 1st line from foo
```

Comment: Great! I think the associative array approach looks much cleaner and more manageable. Thanks for the insight!