# get variables in bash with array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array

`arr=('(appsettings.Dev.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')' '(appsettings.G1.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')' '(appsettings.G2.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')' '(appsettings.G3.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')' '(appsettings.G4.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')' '(appsettings.PROD.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')' '(appsettings.STG.json 'up_np:@' 'up_np:$var@')')`

`iterate=${#arr[@]} ; for (( count=0; count<$iterate;  count++ )); do eval subarr$count=${arr[$count]}; done`
this way, I'm able to get the variables assignment correctly as

`echo subarr1[0] ; subarr3[2]` 
and so on.

however, when I try to
`echo [ "${subarr$count[1]}" - "${subarr$count[2]}" - "${subarr$count[0]}"]`

in the same for-loop, I am not getting the corrected output and throughs an error

`/bin/bash: line 654: ${subarr$count[1]}: bad substitution`

Unable to solve the issue. Kindly help as I have to do the things all dynamic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Comment: Aside from answers provided, consider that bash may not be the best tool for the job if you need complex multidimensional data structures. Your life will be a lot easier using something like python that readily supports complex data structures rather than trying to do a million backflips to force it to work in bash.

Comment: `sh` doesn't support arrays at all; why are you using the sh tag here?

Comment: @tjm3772 - It is clean, but I'm still struggling to solve my problem. 

@ CharlesDuffy - I have removed the sh tag

Comment: Agree that `namerefs` are the best solution, but after scratching my head for a minute, recalled that `count=3; eval echo  "\${subarr$count[1]}"` might give you a clue (which others will hate (-; AND realistically is the long term path to insanity AND we're assuming that no other shell meta chars will appear in the value of the arr variable ). . Also, you could do this in `gawk` which does support multi-dim arrays. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell doesn't do one round of expansion to expand the variable name and then another round to extract the value at the index. Use namerefs here:

```bash
declare -n "a=subarr$count"
echo [ "${a[1]}" - "${a[2]}" - "${a[0]}" ]
```

You can see the pain trying to force bash to handle multi-dimensional arrays when the language doesn't support it. Perhaps you should be working with a different tool.