# How to execute a command saved in a variable in linux and save the result in a new variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am executing a series of commands and I hope to achieve the following effect:

1. I need to echo the command before the execution.
2. Execute the command and save the results to a bash variable, *including incorrect results*.
3. Obtain *execution results and execution status* to determine whether subsequent commands need to be executed

**Similar to the following**:

- cmd_var.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

log(){
  echo "$(date +"[%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S]:")" "$@"
}

grep_proc_cmd="ps -ef | grep endless_loop.sh | grep -v grep"
log "exec command: $grep_proc_cmd"
exec_ret=$($grep_proc_cmd 2>&1)

if [ $? != 0 ];then
  log "exec failed: $exec_ret"
  exit 1
fi
log "exec successfully: ret: [$exec_ret]"
```

- **Actual**

The error reported when executing the above script is as follows:

```bash
$ bash var_cmd.sh 
[20240301 01:56:26]: exec command: ps -ef | grep endless_loop.sh | grep -v grep
[20240301 01:56:26]: exec failed: error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.



For more details see ps(1).
```

- **Expect**

The result of executing the command variable in the terminal is stored in the result variable(in `exec_ret`).

```bash
[20240301 01:56:26]: exec command: ps -ef | grep endless_loop.sh | grep -v grep
[20240301 01:56:26]: exec successfully: ret: [ec2user      20384 4185646  0 01:53 pts/16   00:00:00 bash endless_loop.sh]
```

Please tell me how to achieve the desired effect, and further, whether there is a situation where the variable saving command is **applicable to all variables**.

Such as:

```bash
kill_cmd="ps -ef | grep A | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs sudo kill -9"

cp_cmd="cp A B"
```

- **other way**

```
#!/bin/bash

grep_proc_func(){
  log "exec: ps -ef | grep endless_loop.sh | grep -v grep"
  exec_ret=$(ps -ef | grep endless_loop.sh | grep -v grep 2>&1)
  exec_status=$?
}

main(){
  grep_proc_func
  if [ "$exec_status" != 0 ];then
    log "exec failed: $exec_ret"
    exit 1
  fi
  log "exec successfully: ret: $exec_ret"

  # other cmd function
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: You have to use `eval` to parse the shell syntax in the command. `$(eval "$grep_proc_cmd")`

Comment: Any reason you're not using `pgrep`?

Comment: Mind, the general advice is "don't do that", and for good reasons: Code should be stored as functions, not strings. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to understand why `$cmd` doesn't work on its own, and [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) to understand why `eval "$cmd"` is a bad idea.

Comment: (the shell's execution makes a firm boundary between data and code -- only code is parsed for syntax -- and using `eval` in any case where data might have been substituted into the string that you're running blurs that line, increasing your vulnerability to injection attacks).

Comment: Re: your "other way", here's a simpler example. `grep_log_proc() { ps -ef | grep endless_loop.sh | grep -v grep 2>&1; }` lets you then print the function's definition with `declare -f grep_log_proc`, and run it and collect results with `out=$(grep_log_proc); rc=$?`. If you want to store exit status and output to arbitrary variables, any of the _many_ Q&A entries we have about indirect assignment cover that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added at the end of the question (**ther way"") whether it is consistent with what you expressed: *Code should be stored as functions, not strings*

Comment: ...it succeeds as storing code as a function, but it fails at being either DRY (repeating the command twice, one for logging and again for execution, is unfortunate) or firmly accurate (`echo "..."` is often [much less useful and accurate than you'd think](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)).

Comment: If you want to print an argument list in a way that's 100% guaranteed to evaluate back to the original strings, that's something more like `printf '%s\n' "Running with arguments: ${*@Q}" >&2` (one of the few times `$*` is more applicable than `$@`; `"$@"` should be used when actually expanding arguments onto a list)

Comment: btw, as a rule, better to just use `if grep_proc_func; then` rather than inspecting `$?` directly if all you care about is whether the status indicates success.

Comment: (a wrapper to add the printing and storage might look like: `run_logged() { declare -n output_var=$1; shift; declare -n rc_var=$1; shift; funcname=$1; shift; printf '%q ' "$funcname" "$@" >&2 && echo >&2; declare -f "$funcname" >&2 || { output_var=; rc_var=254; return 254; }; rc_var=0; output_var=$(funcname "$@") || rc_var=$?; return "$rc_var"; }`)

Comment: ...in that case you'd use `if run_logged grep_proc_func grep_out grep_rc; then ...` to both branch on the output _and_ store the output and rc. But I hope that example isn't a good representation of real code; checking the process table that way generally indicates you're doing something wrong (like not taking advantage of your operating system's process supervision tools).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, I tried to format your `run_logged() { declare -n output_var=$1; shift;  ...`, but I failed. If it is convenient, can you expand it in Answers? Thanks!

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/RoyalBewitchedApplet#main.sh for an online REPL with a formatted version of the above demonstrated. (Can't add it as an answer without reopening the question)

Comment: BTW, note that if you need a version that works with old versions of bash (like the one Apple ships), that calls for using some different techniques instead of `declare -n`. Those are covered in [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006), or to find relevant answers in Stack Overflow, a good starting point is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash

Comment: Given `cmd="ps -ef | grep foo"`, `$($cmd)` is like `$("ps" "-ef" "|" "grep" "foo")`. The pipe is data now, *not* a metachar, so it doesn't work. `psgrep(){ ps -ef|grep foo; }; $(psgrep)` avoids that.  Also, don't `grep -v grep`; rather, add metachars: `ps -ef | grep 'foo[.]sh'`doesn't match itself. Finally... please, don't jump straight to [kill -9](http://web.archive.org/web/20110730051506/http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter). Don't kill the fly with a shotgun, at *least* until he has evaded a more reasonable attempt. ;)