# Does there exist a dummy command that doesn't change input and output?

Tags: linux, bash

Does there exist a dummy command in Linux, that doesn't change the input and output, and takes  arguments that doesn't do anything?

```
cmd1 | dummy --tag="some unique string here" | cmd2
```

My interest in such dummy command is to be able to identify the processes, then I have multiple `cmd1 | cmd2` running.

Comment: But won't you need this `dummy` to pass output of `cmd1`'s to `cmd2`?

Comment: Use the process id to `identify the process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable for that:

```
cmd1 | USELESS_VAR="some unique string here" cmd2
```

This has the advantage that Jonathan commented about of not performing an extra copy on all the data.

Comment: Interesting! How can I see the see the `USELESS_VAR` for each of the processes, hence identify them?

Answer (score 1):

To create the command that you want, make a file called `dummy` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat
```

Place the file in your PATH and make it executable (`chmod a+x dummy`).  Because `dummy` ignores its arguments, you may place any argument on the command line that you choose.  Because the body of `dummy` runs `cat` (with no arguments), `dummy` will echo stdin to stdout.

#### Alternative

> My interest in such dummy command is to be able to identify the processes, then I have multiple cmd1 | cmd2 running.

As an alternative, consider

```
pgrep cmd1
```

It will show a process ID for every copy of `cmd` that is running.  As an example:

```
$ pgrep getty
3239
4866
4867
4893
```

This shows that four copies of `getty` are running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on your use case, but if you want to be able to "tag" different invocations of a command for the convenience of a sysadmin looking at a *ps* listing, you might be able to rename `argv[0]` to something suitably informative:

```
$:- perl -E 'exec {shift} "FOO", @ARGV' sleep 60 &
$:- perl -E 'exec {shift} "BAR", @ARGV' sleep 60 &
$:- perl -E 'exec {shift} "BAZ", @ARGV' sleep 60 &
$:- ps -o cmd=
-bash
FOO 60
BAR 60
BAZ 60
ps -o cmd
```

You don't have to use perl's [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html).  There are other conveniences for this, too, such as DJB's [`argv0`](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/argv0.html), RedHat's [`doexec`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/doexec), and [bash itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3251550/132382).

Comment: Wonderful answer! Made my day

Answer (score 0):

You should find a better way of identifying the processes buy anyway, you can use:

```
ln -s /dev/null /tmp/some-unique-file
cmd1 | tee /tmp/some-unique-file | cmd2
```

Comment: Many hundreds GB of data will go through the pipe, so writing it to a file is no good.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes: Make the `/tmp/some-unique-file` into a symlink to `/dev/null`.  But it is still a tad painful.  But then, introducing a process into the middle of the command line like that imposes an enormous overhead (an extra pipe, with extra copying of all the data).  Why not modify `cmd1` and `cmd2` to take the dummy arguments?