# Change process title/name in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, process

There is a **field** in `process` object in **node.js**: `process.title`

That field allows you to change process name displayed in `top` or `ps` command on linux.

Is there some way to do this for and in bash script also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change argv0 in bash so command shows up with different name in ps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251550/how-to-change-argv0-in-bash-so-command-shows-up-with-different-name-in-ps)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the command line reference from **running** processes is possible on *NIX with /proc filesystem :

```sh
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  106 tty4     00:00:01 bash
  719 tty4     00:00:00 ps
$ echo "toto" > /proc/106/comm
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  106 tty4     00:00:01 toto
  719 tty4     00:00:00 ps
$
```

And yes, it's not the prettiest way to do so.