# How to get Python multiprocessing Process() names to handoff to OS utilities like ps, top, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, debian-based

I would like to have the python generated subprocesses (multiprocessing) report their python-assigned dict "name" into the system level log such that I can use existing process tracking utilities, without having to map the PID individually to the name provided in my application.

Initially, when spawning a `multiprocessing.Process(...name="procName")` I can see that the ps utility does not inherit the name provided internally in Python's Process properties, but instead as a duplicate of the parent thread. (This feature limitation is reasonable from both software and OS perspective)
[image: OS process name not being handed python's process name parameter]
(OS process name not being handed python's process name parameter)

I have done some work arounds to modify the value of the Process using a more direct memory modification via c library through Cython.

This appears to work in some manner, but appears to only appear in ps correctly when the process is defunct.
[image: OS process spawns with parent name assignment, followed by my approach forcing the process name update with lower-level communication clib, as shown by the process name updating (same PID, not shown in snippet though]
(OS process spawns with parent name assignment, followed by my approach forcing the process name update with lower-level communication clib, as shown by the process name updating (same PID, not shown in snippet though)

Can I get this to update on currently-running processes (long running)? In the mean-time I have dumped the processes into a log on-demand...but now also have to cross-reference the PID's to get the Python process names.

EDIT:
here's a dirty quick test script just to demo the approach of modifying on clib. the result "works" as shown above - but only after the child process is complete.

```
from multiprocessing import current_process, Process, active_children
import time

def set_proc_name(newname):
    from ctypes import cdll, byref, create_string_buffer
    libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    buff = create_string_buffer(len(newname)+1)
    buff.value = newname
    s = libc.prctl(15, byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)
    return s

def get_proc_name():
    from ctypes import cdll, byref, create_string_buffer
    libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    buff = create_string_buffer(128)
    # 16 == PR_GET_NAME from <linux/prctl.h>
    libc.prctl(16, byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)
    return buff.value
```

EDIT2:
`setproctitle` package clearly works here as suggested by @AKX - I will dive into this cython library and find out what approach they are using and update...
[image]

Comment: You can try [`setproctitle`](https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle/), e.g. in the `initializer` function of your subprocess.

Comment: get PID via Process,pid() and change it with os.system(bashCommand)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67161935/change-process-title-name-in-bash-script

Comment: simply writing isn't a working solution - The information that you read from the `proc` filesystem is not stored on any media (not even in RAM), so there is nothing to update. The data that you see when you read from the `proc` filesystem is generated on-the-fly in a manner NOT like `named-pipes`, but more like a `file-as-an-interface` to the OS `kernel`. The answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121702/what-happens-when-i-run-the-command-cat-proc-cpuinfo has some very good exploratory information. Different OS flavors handle this differently it appears.