# How to load Java runtime as a DLL

Tags: java, windows

When I start Java-applications with java.exe, every application has the same name in the process-manager. And the Java-processes are not distinguishable.
Is it possible to write a simple C/C++-stub which loads the Java-runtime as a DLL and possibly the commandline-parameters passed to a exported function of the DLL so that the Java-process has its own identity?

Thanks in advance,
Bonita.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882826/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-java-application-process

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-functions-from-c

Comment: @Andreas but that is not what the OP's question is really about... (this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: It is better to use a pre-made java launcher as it is not as trivial as calling a single function. You can also simply copy/rename java.exe btw.