# Change application "Image Name" and "Description" from "JavaFx" standalone app

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8

Well it said already answered but that not solved my issue, all are related to other platforms. I have developed a JavaFX windows app. It works fine but in task manager, it shows 'java.exe' as Image name & 'Java(TM) platform SE Binary' as shown in the attached image. I want to change it to app name like 'appname64.exe/appname32.exe' and 'App name' respectively.

[image]

I am developing it in Netbeans IDE 8.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the name of a Java application process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882826/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-java-application-process)

Comment: @SamuelP. how to change it in javaFx app..?? im not getting that